# Handling + and - signs in XSD definition

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to handle "+"  and "-" signs under a xsd field say sign . How can I write it in the XSD definition for the field called sign ?

The field in the XML should be like

+

Or

-

Answer (score 1):

You could either use an `enumeration` facet listing "+" and "-" as the only two permitted values, or you could use a `pattern` facet with `value="\+|\-"` or `value="[+-]"`

Comment: Yes. Or you could use xs:token if you want to ignore leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael.